# How to migrate from a String property to a Link in OrientDB?

Tags: sql, orientdb, nosql

I have a Class in OrientDB, which is called Book. The book has an `author` property, which is of type String, which contains the author name. I also have an Author class, with the same names for the author, but now I want to connect these two classes.

In short, I want to migrate the `author` property to a LINK reference, to the Author class, which has a name, bio, etc.

So I need to migrate my Book, but how do I do this without losing my data?

Comment: I'm doing a function in javascript to migrate, are you using your db as a graph or as a document ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also execute something like (I din't try it):

```
update Book set author2 = (select from Author where name = $parent.current.author )
update Book set author = author2
update Book remove author2
```

Comment: Thanks! In the end, I used  similar approach, assigning the @rid to a new property, and renaming it in the end.

Answer (score 1):

I tried with this structure

[image]

[image]

I used this function

```
var g=orient.getGraphNoTx();
var books=g.command("sql","select from Book");
var authors=g.command("sql","select from Author");
g.command("sql","create property Book.authors Link Author");
for(i=0;i<books.length;i++){
    var book_author=books[i].getProperty("author");
    for(j=0;j<authors.length;j++){
        var author=authors[j].getProperty("name");
        if(author==book_author){
            var query="update " + books[i].getId() + "set authors = " + authors[j].getId();
            g.command("sql",query);
        }
    }
}
g.command("sql","DROP PROPERTY Book.author FORCE");
g.command("sql","UPDATE Book REMOVE author");
g.command("sql","ALTER property Book.authors name author");
g.command("sql","UPDATE Book REMOVE authors");
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank Alessandro! I ended up with a similar approach, but in Java instead of Javascript. I'm using the DB as a Document/Object db, not as a graph btw.